# Combine Set with @OrderColumn

Tags: java, hibernate

A general suggestion with m-n relations is to use `Set` instead of `List` because it offers better performance for certain operations.

I'm trying to combine this with the annotation `@OrderColumn(name = "position")`. I use this so I don't need a "join table class". I want Hibernate to set the position value according to the position of the element in the set. Therefore I use a `LinkedHashSet`.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "bundle_group_to_bundle", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fk_bundle_group"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fk_bundle"))
@OrderColumn(name = "position", nullable = false)
private Set<Bundle> bundles = new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

I can't get this to work. Hibernate ignores the position attribute completely when reading or writing entities. As soon as I replace this with `List` it works fine.

Does Hibernate support `@OrderColumn` with `Set`?

Note: I tried using `SortedSet` instead of `Set` but that requires either `@Sort` (deprecated) or `@OrderBy` (cannot be used with `@OrderColumn`) which I can't use in my case.

Comment: Same problem. I was surprised I couldn't find any documentation on List being mandatory for @OrderColumn ... but it _seems_ that's the way it is. Would be interested in explanation! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not as much as a Hibernate issue than a Java issue. The `Set` interface doesn't guarantee any order ([Set Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html)). So in Java, you can't use a plain `Set` if you want any kind of sorting or order.

Plus, Hibernate creates his mapping from fields' definition, even if `LinkedHashSet` keeps inserting order, the framework will use the `Set` to do his job. And any entity loaded through hibernate will have a custom implementation of `Set` used, a `PersistentSet`.

On the other hand, `List` and `SortedSet` interfaces preserve order and allow sorting.

Indeed, `Set` generally perform better than `List` on some operation. But if you can't use `SortedSet`, you have limited choices.

Comment: So where in the Javadoc did you read something about the order? Maybe you mixed up the part about unmodifiable set in the last paragraph. It is a Hibernate issue because Hibernate can detect if `Set` and `@OrderColumn` are used together and then don't use `PersistentSet`.

Comment: The document says: `As implied by its name, this interface models the mathematical set abstraction.`
In mathematics, a set is a collection of distinct elements where arrangement and order don't matter [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics).
It is also strongly implied in the document of some method (as `Set.iterator()`) and by the lack of any `sort` method like with `List`.